# удаление памяти, выделенную для динамического массива

Tags: c++, массивы, строки, указатели, память

Дана строка символов, необходимо из этой строки сформировать двумерный динамический массив с заранее известным количеством строк и заранее неизвестным количеством символов в каждой строке без чисел.

`

```
int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
int n;
cout << "введите число элементов" << endl;
cin >> n;
cin.clear();
char *a = new char[n+1];
int L = 0;
char cBuffer;
int iBuffer;
int count = 0;
int counter = 0;
int nomerMax = 0;
gets_s(a, n+1);
cin.getline(a, n+1);
int stroka = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++)
{
while (a[i] == 48 || a[i] == 49 || a[i] == 50 || a[i] == 51 || a[i] == 52 || a[i] == 53 || a[i] == 54 || a[i] == 55 || a[i] == 56 || a[i] == 57)
    i++;
L = i;
    while (!((a[i] == 48) || (a[i] == 49) || (a[i] == 50) || (a[i] == 51) || (a[i] == 52) || (a[i] == 53) || (a[i] == 54) || (a[i] == 55) || (a[i] == 56) || (a[i] == 57)))
{
        if (i == strlen(a))
            break;
    i++;
}

    if (L < i)
        stroka++;
}
cout << "строк разбито: " << stroka << endl;
char **massivPodstrok = new char*[stroka];
int markerStrok = 0;
int maxSize = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++)
{
while (a[i] == 48 || a[i] == 49 || a[i] == 50 || a[i] == 51 || a[i] == 52 || a[i] == 53 || a[i] == 54 || a[i] == 55 || a[i] == 56 || a[i] == 57)
    i++;
L = i;
while (!((a[i] == 48) || (a[i] == 49) || (a[i] == 50) || (a[i] == 51) || (a[i] == 52) || (a[i] == 53) || (a[i] == 54) || (a[i] == 55) || (a[i] == 56) || (a[i] == 57)))
{
    if (i == strlen(a))
        break;
    i++;
}
int h = 0;

    for (int I = L; I < i; I++)
    {
        h++;

        if (maxSize < h)
        {
            maxSize = h;
            nomerMax = count;
        }

    }

    massivPodstrok[count] = new char[h];
    count++;

}
cout << "максимальная длина строки " << maxSize << endl;
cout << "номер строки максимальной длины: " << nomerMax +1 << endl;

count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(a)+1; i++)
{
while (a[i] == 48 || a[i] == 49 || a[i] == 50 || a[i] == 51 || a[i] == 52 || a[i] == 53 || a[i] == 54 || a[i] == 55 || a[i] == 56 || a[i] == 57)
    i++;
L = i;
while (!((a[i] == 48) || (a[i] == 49) || (a[i] == 50) || (a[i] == 51) || (a[i] == 52) || (a[i] == 53) || (a[i] == 54) || (a[i] == 55) || (a[i] == 56) || (a[i] == 57)))
{
    if (i == strlen(a))
        break;
    i++;
}
int h = 0;

for (int I = L; I < i; I++)
{
    iBuffer = a[I];
    cBuffer = (char)iBuffer;
    if (count < stroka)
    {
        massivPodstrok[count][h] = cBuffer;
        cout << massivPodstrok[count][h];
    }
    h++;
}

cout << endl;
count++;

}
cout << count;
for (int i = 0; i < stroka; i++)
delete massivPodstrok[i];
delete[] massivPodstrok;
delete[] a;

_getch();
return 0;
}`
```

проблемка в том, что происходит HEAP CORRUPTION при удалении памяти, помогите плз разобраться где накосячил с выделением памяти под массив

Comment: какие библиотеки использованы?

Comment: @Виталий Китов " заранее известным количеством строк и заранее неизвестным количеством символов в каждой строке" это `std::vector<std::string>`. И никаких проблем с выделением памяти

Comment: но все же вопрос был не о этом. Мало ли что надо человеку.

Comment: ага , очень часто при обучении эти классы запрещены к использованию. Для развития мышления :P

Comment: нет, они запрещены, потому что преподают си, а не с++

Comment: в си нет оператора  new.

Comment: @KoVadim я так понимаю до 11 года с++ не существовало - был только Си? :)

Comment: И на с++ можно писать как на си и как на Фортране... А то что в си нет new ... define в помощь

Comment: сложновато... макросом new-выражение не опишешь...

Comment: @KoVadim тоже мне новость: С++, изначально, был всего-лишь расширением Си. Так что в этом ничего удивительного.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch не совсем так, он использует синтаксис. Страустрап бьет канделяброй тех кто утверждает это. Правила в ряде мест различались с самого начала, а сейчас и подавно, хотя Си многое позаимствовал у С++

Comment: Я  согласен  с  KoVadim - если вы изучаете С++ или работаете, то нужно  стараться написать именно на С++, особенно что вопрос задается по этому тэгу.  Такой код, что написал автор вопроса, отбивает желание разобраться

Comment: @ARHovsepyan  формально написано на С++ (соглашусь , что ужасно написано). Стандартная библиотека есть стандартная библиотека а не часть языка и наша образовательная система их игнорирует. Вышеупомянутые классы не обязаны быть реализованы на конкретной платформе, но если они реализованы, то должны соответствовать стандарту.

Comment: Стандартная библиотека (STL) уже давно часть языка. Она описана в одном документе с языком.

Answer (score 4):

tl;dr

Вместо delete massivPodstrok[i]

```
delete[] massivPodstrok[i]
```

Вы выделяете каждую строку как массив

```
massivPodstrok[count] = new char[h];
```

что приводит к вызову оператора new[], следовательно надо использовать правильный delete

Так же в циклах while возможен выход за границу массива, т.к. значение i не проверяется.

```
 while (a[i] == 48 || a[i] == 49 || a[i] == 50 || a[i] == 51 || a[i] == 52 || a[i] == 53 || a[i] == 54 || a[i] == 55 || a[i] == 56 || a[i] == 57)
        i++;
```

В крайнем случае так:

```
 if(a[i] == 48 || a[i] == 49 || a[i] == 50 || a[i] == 51 || a[i] == 52 || a[i] == 53 || a[i] == 54 || a[i] == 55 || a[i] == 56 || a[i] == 57)
       continue;
```

Что эти коды означают?  А лучше так

```
 #include <cctype> 
 // ...

 if(std::isdigit(a[i]))
```

В сумме

```
    for (int i = 0, len = strlen(a); i < len; i++)
    {
        if(std::isdigit(a[i]))  continue;
        L = i;
        while (!std::isdigit(a[i]))
        {
            if (i == len)
                break;
            i++;
        }

        if (L < i)
            stroka++;
    }
```

Нужно пересмотреть метод работы. Одна и та же работа выполняется 3 раза. Вместо массива строк создайте уж связанный список тогда. И неужели нельзя использовать стандартные контейнеры?

Если пользователь ошибся при вводе:

```
cin >> n;
```

Вернет ложь и n=0, программа упадет.
Разобраться, не имея  примера входных данных и ожидаемого вывода сложно.

Comment: Мм не понял а как надо то?

Comment: @ВиталийКитов вместо `delete massivPodstrok[i]` нужно использовать delete[] , т.е. `delete[] massivPodstrok[i]`, т.к. вы до этого выделяли для каждой i-ой массива подстроки не один елемент, а массив. Т.е. если вы использовали тогда `new[]`, то и `delete` должен быть соответсвующий, в данном случае `delete[]`

Comment: Это верно. Но на практике не будет причной падения для таких типов данных.

Comment: @AnT я такое видел и правил.. причем падать может весьма загадочно, всегда на выходе из функции или удалении чего-то_потом_. На  MS VC и судя по _getch() с подчеркиванием это оно самое. В любом случае это UB

Comment: @Swift: С тем что после `new[]` следует всегда использовать именно `delete[]` спору нет. Однако на практике неправильное использование `delete` в такой ситуации "падать" может только для типов с нетривиальным деструктором.

Comment: Допустим вводим строку qwerty124asd5600phd. Необходимо чтобы создался массив из строк qwerty, asd, phd причем чтобы память для каждой строки выделялась  сколько нужно, в зависимости от длины получившихся строк. Для строки qwerty вроде как 7 ячеек памяти (6 + 1 ячейка означающая конец строки, если я ничего не напутал) для строки asd и phd соответственно 4

Comment: @Виталий Китов: "Надо-то" использовать литералы `'0'`, `'1'`, `'2'` и т.д. вместо этих неуместных "магических" кодов `48`, `49` и т.д. Или, лучше (!), не заниматься фигней, а воспользоваться стандартной функцией `std::isdigit`.

Comment: @AnT и вообще сохранять результат в связанный список. А строку  ввода - в строку а не мучать пользователя завуалированными вопросами  о длине строки